# Can an attachment be split in an HL7 file and recreated after the message is transmitted?

Tags: hl7, hapi

I am using the HAPI parser to parse the HL7 files that come through my company.  We are working on moving attachments through the OBX segment of the HL7 file.  There are some validators that my stack uses that will not allow an attachment over 64k to pass.  Is there a way to take multiple OBX segments and break an attachment up and then recreate it after it has passed through the wire to the other side?

Answer (score 0):

HL7 identifies two possible cases and uses continuation pointer protocol for each. These cases are:

- A single segment may be too large. HL7 uses the "ADD" segment to handle breaking a single segment into several smaller segments.
- A single HL7 message may be too large. HL7 uses the DSC segment (in conjunction with the MSH-14 filed)  and the continuation protocol to handle message fragmentation.

Chapter 2 “Controls” of the HL7v2 spec talks about it in more details.